# MSAccess - Disable Right-Click on Tabbed View?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access DB App that I have elected to use in Tabbed mode, where each new form opens in its own new Tab:

[image]

I'd like to prohibit user-access to right-click functions (Design-View, Close, etc.).

Are there any setting to disable or hide these functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the File menu choose Options, then the Current Database tab. There is an option there to **Allow Default Shortcut Menus**. Unchecking this is the simplest way but it does disable the default shortcut menus entirely. (This doesn't *prohibit* the user though, as someone who knows what they are doing could find and check this option.)

Otherwise you might investigate creating an [MDE file](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/about-mde-files-mdb-HP005239302.aspx) which, among other things, disables all Design Views. Keep a copy of the original database though, as you cannot reverse, or revert, an MDE file.

> Be sure to keep a copy of your original Access database. If you need
>   to modify the design of forms, reports, or modules in an MDE file, you
>   must modify the original Access database, and then resave it as an MDE
>   file.

Comment: Perfect.  That option does just what I need.  My typical user won't go looking for the option to flip back the option.  This helps ensure forms are closed in a controlled manner, via the btnClose() event and associated code.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can customize the Short Cut Menu to remove the Design View option. In Form Design View invoke Access Help and enter the phrase "shortcut menu" then select "Customize a shortcut menu"

Comment: The Shortcut Menu option from a Form's Design View (in the Form's properties) only disables right-clicking within the form area, not from the Tab.